# True or False: Locks are to synchronized blocks as gotos are to structured programming?

Tags: java, concurrency

Is this a fair analogy to make? I think I can think of some scenarios where you *have* to use locks, but I'm not sure if they're necessary.

For instance, here is a loop I recently wrote to perform waiting on a thread to update a list. I apologize if this is terrible java, as I am a native linux kernel-ite:

```
ReentrantLock lock;

...

while(true) {
    lock.lock();
    int size = queue.size();

    if (size == 0) {
        try {
            lock.unlock();

            Thread.sleep(3600000);
            continue;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            lock.lock();
            size = queue.size();
            if (size == 0) {
                lock.unlock();
                continue;
            }
        }
    }

    VPacket p = queue.getFirst();
    lock.unlock();

    return p;
}
```

Where `VPacket` is a packet for the particular protocol I'm writing.

This analogy came to mind as I pondered the `Collections.synchonizedList class`, thinking about how I can do this without such C-like tricks.

Comment: In structured programming gotos are useful.  Locks can be useful in synchronized programming, but not the best option, generally.  So, it is a tool, whether it is the best one is up to the programmer.  So, if your question whether locks are a valid tool, then yes, but are the critical then I would disagree.  I think your question is poorly worded, as I am not certain what you are looking for.

Comment: goto is used all the time to break out of blocks, e.g. `break`. Exceptions are just posh gotos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, synchronized blocks predate classes like ReentrantLock by many years; the classes in that package were introduced to provide some more sophisticated and higher-level capabilities than what Java the language had previously offered -- although many of those capabilities are needed only in very specific circumstances.

But in this specific case, I would say that using a synchronized block (and wait(N) instead of sleep(N)!) would be more elegant. I understand your analogy, and I'd say that *sometimes* it holds; certainly for this sort of run-of-the-mill-case, using a synchronized block is like using the RAII pattern in C++ -- it's the clearest way to make sure things are cleaned up when needed.

Comment: +1 for the important note about waiting rather than sleeping.

Comment: what specific services does wait provide?

Comment: @Alex: wait() is very much like the unlock/sleep combo you already have there, except it's atomic, and it has the added bonus that you can't "wake up" without reacquiring the lock.

Comment: ... and whereas `sleep()` can only be interrupted using `interrupt()`, which results in an exception being thrown, `wait()` can be signaled with `notify()`. Much cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

In general, designing concurrent data structures that behave (and perform) well is a very tricky task. It is considered a Good Thing(tm) if you don't implement everything yourself using low-level tools, but rather use more high-level abstractions available in the standard library.

For your task, I'd rather use a [BlockingQueue](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) or [BlockingDeque](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingDeque.html) which takes care of the synchronization for me.

Comment: My only problem with using the blocking structures is that I need to perform checking of the size and extraction atomically. This leads to a race if I don't have some way to guarantee that nothing will be interleaved between the two operations.

Answer (score 0):

Synchronized blocks are always properly nested by nature, while you *can* misuse locks and forget to unlock. However, the first thing you read about locks is to always use them in a try/finally construct, like this:

```
lock.lock();
try {
    // Do things...
}
finally {
    lock.unlock();
}
```

This is a *strongly* recommended pattern that ensures your locks behave as synchronized blocks.

Locks have several advantages over synchronized blocks:

- They are more efficient than synchronized blocks, although I read that's been fixed in the recent JVM.
- Some locks can be split into read and write locks for increased concurrency.
- They can be passed around, but then you're out of the safe pattern explained above.

So, IMHO, locks are more like a bigger gun: more powerful, but also more dangerous if you don't know how to use them.

Answer (score -1):

A modified version of the same code, which more optimal IMO :) To answer you question, the analogy is wrong. gotos received a bad reputation because of the way they allowed control flows to escape, causing nightmares. Locks do not allow control to escape in the same sense. Well, you may ask what happens if I acquire a lock and refuse to release it. Not possible with sync blocks. The ideal pattern is to use a try-finally. BTW, concurrent programming is itself a nightmare which cannot be enhanced/reduced.

```
while(true) {
    if(queue.size()==0){
        Thread.sleep(36000);
    }
    lock.lock();
    Vpacket p = null;
    try {
         p = null;
         if(queue.size()!=0) {
              p = queue.pop();
         }
    } finally {
         lock.unlock();
         if(p!=null) {
              return p;
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: checking the queue size outside the lock is most likely not thread safe.

Comment: Aaha! expecting someone to read that. What does the original code do, synchronize access on the queue? No. The queue itself is mutable, I have not reduced any thread safety, just added an optimization for unsync sleep(). To achieve safe queue.size() you have to lock it on the queue object itself

Comment: sorry, that's not correct.  the original code has lock calls around all the queue accesses, so it is thread-safe.

Comment: Umm, still disagree with you :) We actually don't see queue being populated in this snippet, do we? As the queue is declared as an instance variable, for all we know it might be updated by a different Thread. Without the complete code being posted neither of us would be entirely correct!

Comment: Also there is an additional element of stale state which has to be addressed, if the queue is shared across objects. Just using locks in a function block is not entirely sufficient.

Comment: obviously there could be other code which uses the queue in an unsafe manner, but the OP is thread-safe as written (making conjectures about other code which we can't see is kind of silly).  your second comment is wrong again, however:  if used consistently for all access to the queue, using locks _is_ entirely sufficient for thread-safe queue access.

Comment: I strongly disagree with you. Stale state problem does not automatically go away, preventing it is problem that requires even more attention than lock/sync. I am surprised at the way you defend  that the queue is consistently accessed using locks. I agree that any data structure can be made thread safe by allowing consistent access via locks. The question is whether it is the case or not. For eg. consider queue.pop() in thread 1 using lock 'l1' and queue.pop() in thread 2 using lock 'l2'. Forget about 'l2' what happens if a thread t3 calls queue.pop().

Comment: Preventing stale state problem that requires even more attention than lock/sync and cause of quite a few headaches. As we are not locking the queue, my argument is still valid. We are still making conjectures, I disagree that they are silly.

Comment: i have no idea what you are trying to describe with multiple locks.  the point is that the OP used the _same_ lock consistently around all access to the queue.  this is equivalent to using a synchronized block on the same object around all queue access.  that makes the code, as written, thread-safe.

Comment: The point I was trying to make is that making a single code block be mutexed is not sufficient. The argument you made was "if used consistently for all access to the queue, using locks is entirely sufficient for thread-safe queue".  The correct argument is using the *same* locks for all access flows/invariants on the data structure. Which is not clear in the code shared.

Comment: by your argument, no code can ever be proved thread-safe, as one could always introduce _other_ code which breaks the invariant.  while technically true, it does not add anything useful to the discussion.  additionally, your solution above is _provably_ not thread-safe, hence also not helpful.